# What is the average UDP/TCP packet round trip (in ms) over wifi (b/g) between mobile devices?

Tags: tcp, udp, wifi, android-wifi, roundtrip

I doing a feasibility study. Imagine a local multiplayer game between mobile devices (eg: 4 players sitting around a table). Each device sends game data to one another. There is no "server" as every devices acts as one (ie p2p), although it may be a classical "client server" architecture

With this setting:

**a) what is the average round trip time for a UDP packet ? State your UDP packet size/OS/device/Wifi technology (eg: b/g) if possible.**
**b) what is the average round trip time for a TCP packet ? State your TCP** packet size/OS/device/Wifi technology (eg: b/g) if possible.

If you have experience/hard data about this, I would appreciate a lot you share them here.

Thanks

Comment: Default RTT time is 3000ms for Windows and 1000ms for Ubuntu.